# Use Class Field Other than ID or Slug in URL

Tags: python-3.x, django, url

I want to access an object by an field other then ID or Slug for Django's `DetailView`, like so:

http://example.com/product/name

My **model** is like so:

```
class Product (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Full name")
```

**View:**

```
class ProductDetail(DetailView):

    model = Product
```

**URLConf:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('product/<name>', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product-detail'),
]
```

I'm not sure what should go in the URLConf.

Note that my templates are working and I can access the object by ID as usual:

http://example.com/product/1

Comment: Your `name` column is not unique. There may be multiple objects with the same `name`.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for pointing this out. Still prototyping, so I'll take this into account when I start fleshing out the models more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the [**`get_object(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    model = Product

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_object_or_404(Product, name=self.kwargs['name'])
```

That being said, the idea of a *slug* is to make visually pleasant URLs, if you use certain characters, etc. these are percent encoded, and result in "*ugly*" URLs.

As [@Selcuk says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111185/use-class-field-other-than-id-or-slug-in-url/64111217#comment113370723_64111185), the `name` of your `Product` is not *unique* this means that the same name can refer to *multiple* products. If you want to use this in the URL, you thus should make it unique, and you probably better *enforce* this at the database layer:

```
class Product (models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text='Full name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The product names in this case are super simple, single word descriptors so name is ideal. But your point about slugs is well taken.